# Can't have authorization for the app_installations methode

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-api, github3.py

I'm working on a github application and my actual task is to  retrieve list of github user account / github organization on which the app has been installed.
So basically, I'll be using the [app_installations()](https://github3.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-reference/github.html#github3.github.GitHub.app_installations) Method in [Github3.py](https://github3.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) Library.
This method require authentication. So by running the following code :

```
def get_users():

    user = "bilel.e***********"
    password = "5QPN74dHD******"   

    gh = login(user, password)
    #gh is an instance of <class 'github3.github.GitHub'>

    scopes = ['user', 'repo']

    auth = gh.authorize(user, password, scopes)
    ghi = gh.app_installations()

    return ()
get_users()
```

I receive the following output :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ghe-admin-app/service.py", line 33, in <module>
    get_users()
  File "ghe-admin-app/service.py", line 29, in get_users
    auth = gh.authorize(user, password, scopes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/github3/github.py", line 503, in authorize
    json = self._json(self._post(url, data=data), 201)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/github3/models.py", line 156, in _json
    raise exceptions.error_for(response)
github3.exceptions.UnprocessableEntity: 422 Validation Failed
```

I should mention that I tried to put a wrong password on purpose and the result was as expected :

```
github3.exceptions.AuthenticationFailed: 401 Bad credentials
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed issue ! 
I was using the wrong Authentication method. 
I should use login_as_app(private_key_pem=key_file_pem, app_id=app_id) instead in order to use the app_installations() method.